# Which is more efficient - setting color filter first and then setting bitmap or setting bitmap and then setting color filter?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am inflating many imageviews dynamically, each having different color filter.

Sometimes the app gets slaggy and UI starts sticking. I did some research and now I am loading bitmap in background thread.

However, my question is whether setting bitmap to image view first and then setting color filter is more efficient or setting color filter first and then setting bitmap?

Comment: how are you applying the color filter ?

Comment: imageview.setColorFilter(color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl:dr

Setting color filter first saves you one applyColorMode and one invalidate method Call. Apply Color Mode does nothing when you have no colorMod set and the onDraw call isn't too expensive in this case too, so it actually makes no difference.

### Releavant Source Code from ImageView

If you call set Color Filter first this happens:

First the Image View calls setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf)

```
 public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        if (mColorFilter != cf) {
            mColorFilter = cf;
            mHasColorFilter = true;
            mColorMod = true;
            applyColorMod();
            invalidate();
        }
    }
```

this applys the ColorMod and then invalidates

```
  private void applyColorMod() {
        // Only mutate and apply when modifications have occurred. This should
        // not reset the mColorMod flag, since these filters need to be
        // re-applied if the Drawable is changed.
        if (mDrawable != null && mColorMod) {
            mDrawable = mDrawable.mutate();
            if (mHasColorFilter) {
                mDrawable.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
            }
            mDrawable.setXfermode(mXfermode);
            mDrawable.setAlpha(mAlpha * mViewAlphaScale >> 8);
        }
    }
```

Now you set the imageBitmap

```
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    // Hacky fix to force setImageDrawable to do a full setImageDrawable
    // instead of doing an object reference comparison
    mDrawable = null;
    if (mRecycleableBitmapDrawable == null) {
        mRecycleableBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(), bm);
    } else {
        mRecycleableBitmapDrawable.setBitmap(bm);
    }
    setImageDrawable(mRecycleableBitmapDrawable);
}
```

this calls setImageDrawable

```
public void setImageDrawable(@Nullable Drawable drawable) {
    if (mDrawable != drawable) {
        mResource = 0;
        mUri = null;
        final int oldWidth = mDrawableWidth;
        final int oldHeight = mDrawableHeight;
        updateDrawable(drawable);
        if (oldWidth != mDrawableWidth || oldHeight != mDrawableHeight) {
            requestLayout();
        }
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

calling updateDrawable before invalidation:

```
  @UnsupportedAppUsage
    private void updateDrawable(Drawable d) {
        if (d != mRecycleableBitmapDrawable && mRecycleableBitmapDrawable != null) {
            mRecycleableBitmapDrawable.setBitmap(null);
        }
        boolean sameDrawable = false;
        if (mDrawable != null) {
            sameDrawable = mDrawable == d;
            mDrawable.setCallback(null);
            unscheduleDrawable(mDrawable);
            if (!sCompatDrawableVisibilityDispatch && !sameDrawable && isAttachedToWindow()) {
                mDrawable.setVisible(false, false);
            }
        }
        mDrawable = d;
        if (d != null) {
            d.setCallback(this);
            d.setLayoutDirection(getLayoutDirection());
            if (d.isStateful()) {
                d.setState(getDrawableState());
            }
            if (!sameDrawable || sCompatDrawableVisibilityDispatch) {
                final boolean visible = sCompatDrawableVisibilityDispatch
                        ? getVisibility() == VISIBLE
                        : isAttachedToWindow() && getWindowVisibility() == VISIBLE && isShown();
                d.setVisible(visible, true);
            }
            d.setLevel(mLevel);
            mDrawableWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mDrawableHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            applyImageTint();
            applyColorMod();
            configureBounds();
        } else {
            mDrawableWidth = mDrawableHeight = -1;
        }
    }
```